# studying the series $\sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^ {2}}$

Tags: real-analysis

studying the series $\sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^ {2}}$.

I've tried with the root criterion

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n(\log n)^ {2}}}>1$
and the series should diverge.

But I'm not sure 
Can someone help me to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that that limit is equal to $1$, not bigger.

On the other hand, you can use the integral test: in order to determine whether the integral$$\int_2^\infty\frac1{x\log^2x}\,\mathrm dx$$converges or not, use the fact that iy is equal to$$\int_2^\infty\frac{\log'x}{\log^2x}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can also use the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the integral test to show that  all series $\;\displaystyle\sum_\limits{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n(\log n)^{\alpha}}$ converge if and only if $\alpha >1$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on
Wojowu's answer,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \dfrac1{k\ln^2(k)}
&\le \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \dfrac1{k\ln^2(2^n)}\\
&\le 2^n\dfrac1{2^n(n \ln 2)^2}\\
&= \dfrac1{n^2 \ln^2 2}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these converges,

Note that,
for $a > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \dfrac1{k\ln^{1+a}(k)}
&\le \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \dfrac1{k\ln^{1+a}(2^n)}\\
&\le 2^n\dfrac1{2^n(n \ln 2)^{1+a}}\\
&= \dfrac1{n^{1+a} \ln^{1+a} 2}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these converges.

Also note that

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \dfrac1{k\ln(k)}
&\ge \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \dfrac1{k\ln(2^{n+1})}\\
&\ge 2^n\dfrac1{2^{n+1}(n \ln 2)}\\
&= \dfrac1{2n \ln 2}\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of these diverges.